# How to "bin" a numpy array using custom (non-linearly spaced) buckets?

Tags: numpy, scipy, binning

How to "bin" the bellow array in numpy so that:

```
import numpy as np
bins = np.array([-0.1 , -0.07, -0.02,  0.  ,  0.02,  0.07,  0.1 ])
array = np.array([-0.21950869, -0.02854823,  0.22329239, -0.28073936, -0.15926265,
              -0.43688216,  0.03600587, -0.05101109, -0.24318651, -0.06727875])
```

That is replace each of the `values` in `array` with the following:

```
-0.1 where `value` < -0.085
-0.07 where -0.085 <= `value` < -0.045
-0.02 where -0.045 <= `value` < -0.01
0.0 where -0.01 <= `value` < 0.01
0.02 where 0.01 <= `value` < 0.045
0.07 where 0.045 <= `value` < 0.085
0.1 where `value` >= 0.085
```

The expected output would be:

```
array = np.array([-0.1, -0.02,  0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1,  0.02, -0.07, -0.1, -0.07])
```

I recognise that numpy has a `digitize` function however it returns the index of the bin not the bin itself. That is:

```
np.digitize(array, bins)
np.array([0, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 2])
```

Comment: Where did you set the bin separator values?

Comment: The separator values were created manually and are only to illustrate the method of binning (closest value). This is as opposed to grouping all values between 1 and 2 to either 1 or 2. E.g. 1.02 to 1 or 2.

Comment: @Divakar Sorry forgot to add the expected output - updated the post to include it

Comment: Shouldn't the last elem be `-0.07` . Similarly third last one too.

Comment: @Divakar You're right, I went over it again and fixed it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get those mid-values by averaging across consecutive bin values in pairs. Then, use `np.searchsorted` or `np.digitize` to get the indices using the mid-values. Finally, index into `bins` for the output.

Mid-values :

```
mid_bins = (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])/2.0
```

Indices with `searchsorted` or `digitze` :

```
idx = np.searchsorted(mid_bins, array)
idx = np.digitize(array, mid_bins)
```

Output :

```
out = bins[idx]
```